# Script is triggering but nothing happens?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to create a script that moves data from one sheet to another when I mark it as completed in a particular column. Using some other code I found on the internet, I have this, but when I go in and change that status to completed nothing happens. The trigger page in google apps script says it's executing, but it isn't doing anything to the actual sheet. Here is the code:

```
    function onEdit(e) {
  if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() == "Planner" && e.value == "Completed"){ //If the edit was on Planner marking the Status "Completed"
  var spr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var myRange = e.range.offset(0,-3,0,3).getValue() //get the information from Planner
    //find the first row of Calendar where completed assignments is blank
    var column = spr.getRange('O:O');
  var values = column.getValues(); // get all data in one call
  var ct = 0;
  while ( values[ct][0] != "" ) {
    ct++;
    ct++;
     e.source.getSheetByName("Calendar").getRange(ct,15,1,3).setValues(myRange).getValues(); //copy the values from Planner to Calendar
     e.source.getSheetByName("Planner").getRange(myRange).setValues("").getValues(); //delete values from Planner
  ;}
  return (ct);
}
    }
```

I assume something is wrong with it but I don't know what. I've never used apps script before so I honestly don't know what I'm doing. Here is the sheet:
[Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1S2y5_r5S2U6V8zssQ27q3BB0QQ9DwAxunBhIIilCpnE/edit?usp=sharing)

I want to move completed homework from the planner sheet to the calendar sheet when I change the status. Thanks so much for any help!!

EDIT:
I used lamblichus's code and it works great except that I still want to delete the data from the Planner Sheet after I move it. I tried this code and it didn't work:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const ss = e.source;
  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() == "Planner" && e.value == "Completed") {
    var otherData = range.offset(0,-3,1,3).getValues();
    var currentClass = range.offset(0,-4).getMergedRanges()[0].getValue();
    var [task,,date] = otherData[0];
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Calendar");
    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange("O1").getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).offset(1,0,1,3);
    targetRange.setValues([[date,task,currentClass]]);
    var initialSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Planner");
    var initialRange = initialSheet.range.offset(0,-3,1,3);
    initialRange.clearContent(); //delete values from Planner
  }
}
```

Comment: I see you currently have set formulas to populate the data in `Calendar` (columns B to D). I was about to provide an updated script to solve this, but this would mess with the formulas. In that case, before providing an answer, my question would be, do you want to keep these formulas, or you want to replace them with a script?

Comment: I have it set to populate uncompleted assignments by order of due date in calendar, but once it's completed I want it to move to another column. At that point I don't need those assignments in the initial calendar column but I still want the uncompleted assignments populating there

Comment: From what I can see, the formulas are populating all assignments to columns B-D and that messes with the script, which is supposed to copy data to cells that are to be written by the formulas. Therefore, both cannot coexist, at least without any change to the formulas. Can you please clarify that?

Comment: I want the formulas to populate to columns B-D. I want the script to move data to column O.

Comment: My apologies, I misunderstood the situation before. I just posted an answer with a possible solution, I hope it's useful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issues and solution:

There are several issues with your current code:

- If you want to check the sheet name, you have to use [Sheet.getName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getName()). [SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivespreadsheet) just returns the active `spreadsheet`, not `sheet`, and not its name anyway.
- If you want to get values from multiple cells, you should use [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues), not [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue()).
- The third parameter of [offset](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset,-numrows,-numcolumns) corresponds to the number of rows of the resulting range. Therefore, it should not be `0`.
- The "Class" name is in a merged range, and only the top-left cell in a merged range includes the corresponding value. To get that value, you can use [getMergedRanges](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getmergedranges) and retrieve the first element in the resulting array. Since `getValue()` returns the value in the top-left cell of a range, it will return the "Class" name.

#### Code sample:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const ss = e.source;
  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() == "Planner" && e.value == "Completed") {
    var otherDataRange = range.offset(0,-3,1,3);
    var otherData = otherDataRange.getValues();
    var currentClass = range.offset(0,-4).getMergedRanges()[0].getValue();
    var [task,,date] = otherData[0];
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Calendar");
    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange("O1").getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).offset(1,0,1,3);
    targetRange.setValues([[date,task,currentClass]]);
    otherDataRange.clearContent();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This script isn't working for me because it's treating "e" as undefined. Is there a way to address that?

Comment: @ellathompson This is an `onEdit` trigger, and it's supposed to be fired by users editing the spreadsheet, not by executing it directly from the script editor. If you execute it from the script editor, `e` is undefined, since it provides information about the context which caused the trigger to run. To see this working, just turn a task to status `Completed` and see how it's copied to the target range.

Comment: Yay!! Thanks so much!! It's working now :) :)

Comment: Actually, one more thing! If i want to delete the assignment from the "Planner" sheet after it gets copied, how could I do that? I tried the above code and couldn't make it work. Thanks so much!

Comment: @ellathompson In that case, just use [clearContent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearcontent) on the source range. See the updated code snippet in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a syntax error on line 14, you put ;}, it should be }; you don't need to tell JavaScript (the coding language that AppScript is based on) when you end comments. But it likes it when you tell it when you end while loops.

Here is the updated code.

```
    function onEdit(e) {
  if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() == "Planner" && e.value == "Completed"){ //If the edit was on Planner marking the Status "Completed"
    var spr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var myRange = e.range.offset(0,-3,0,3).getValue() //get the information from Planner
    //find the first row of Calendar where completed assignments is blank
    var column = spr.getRange('O:O');
    var values = column.getValues(); // get all data in one call
    var ct = 0;
    while ( values[ct][0] != "" ) {
      ct++;
      ct++;
      e.source.getSheetByName("Calendar").getRange(ct,15,1,3).setValues(myRange).getValues(); //copy the values from Planner to Calendar
      e.source.getSheetByName("Planner").getRange(myRange).setValues("").getValues(); //delete values from Planner
    };
    return (ct);
  };
}
```